# How to get the true/false count from a bit field into two separate columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, bit

I need to create a query that will sum the number of True(1) and False(0) into two separate columns from one bit field.

I'm joining 3 tables and need it to be something like:

Attribute | Class | Pass | Fail

I will be grouping on Attribute and Class.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ColumnName = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Pass, 
SUM(CASE WHEN ColumnName = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Fail
```

Comment: I went down the rabbit hole of trying to use a PIVOT, when this was all I needed - so much easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

This works (at least in SQL 2008)

```
SELECT SUM(Passed + 0) PASS , SUM(1 - Passed) FAIL
```

I am adding 0 to Passed in the first sum as a short hand way of converting from bit to int since you can't sum bits directly.

Comment: PostgreSQL works with `SUM(CAST(Passed as Integer)) PASS, SUM(1 - CAST(Passed AS Integer) FAIL`.

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
declare @table table (columnName bit)
insert into @table values (1)
insert into @table values (1)
insert into @table values (1)
insert into @table values (1)
insert into @table values (1)
insert into @table values (0)
insert into @table values (0)
insert into @table values (0)
insert into @table values (0)

SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN ColumnName = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS True1
  , SUM(CASE WHEN ColumnName = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS False0
from @Table
```

OUTPUT:

```
True1       False0
----------- -----------
5           4

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be

```
SELECT Attribute, Class
       COUNT(CASE WHEN ColumnName = 1 THEN 1 END) Pass,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN ColumnName = 0 THEN 1 END) Fail FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY Attribute, Class
```

Comment: This will result in the number of results including both pass and fail. Should be Sum

Comment: No it won't. If the value of ColumnName doesn't match then it will return null, which isn't counted by COUNT.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    Attribute,
    Class,
    SUM(CASE BitField WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Pass],
    SUM(CASE BitField WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Fail]
FROM 
    Table
GROUP BY
    Attribute,
    Class
```

Answer (score 0):

there is even one more option:

```
SELECT 
   Attribute, 
   Class,
   COUNT(BoolColumnName = 1 or NULL) Pass,
   COUNT(BoolColumnName = 0 or NULL) Fail 
FROM Table
GROUP BY Attribute, Class
```