# How can I get a count of a bit-type column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to determine how many tag-based badges have been awarded in total. My typical strategy is to sum:

```
select sum(TagBased)
from Badges
```

Unfortunately, since `TagBased` is a bit value, I get this error:

> Operand data type bit is invalid for sum operator.

Out of desperation, I tried count:

```
select count(TagBased)
from Badges
```

This counts the number of non-null values, which in this case is identical to `count(*)`. So how can a bit value be used in aggregate?

Answer (score 16):

If you *just* want to look at tag-based badges and don't care about the rest, you can move the test to the where clause:

```
select count(*)
from Badges 
where TagBased = 1
```

The canonical solution would be to cast the bit value to a data type that can be summed:

```
select sum(cast(TagBased as decimal))
from Badges
```

An even more flexible solution is to do the conversion yourself with a [CASE statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
select sum(case TagBased when 1 then 100.0 end)/count(*) tag_based_per
from Badges
```

Alternatively, in newer versions of SQL Server there's an [IIF function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx):

```
select sum(iif(TagBased = 1, 1, 0))
from Badges
```

Finally, if you are golfing, you can trick SQL into converting the bit for you:

```
select sum(TagBased+0)
from Badges
```

The credit for this technique goes to [Kenneth Baltrinic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4503685/1438)'s answer to a more specific question.

For reference (and potential forking): [my test queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/356002/how-many-tag-badges-have-been-awarded?opt.textResults=true).

Comment: maybe you can add this one too `select sum(TagBased&1) from Badges` ?

Comment: I had never been to http://data.stackexchange.com until I saw your last link – now I feel the rest of my evening will evaporate…

Answer (score 4):

Another method to `COUNT` only 1 from `BIT` column is to use [NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx):

```
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(TagBased,0)) AS result
FROM Badges b;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/409598/how-many-tag-badges-have-been-awarded)**</kbd>

---

One more method using [SIGN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188420.aspx):

```
SELECT SUM(SIGN(TagBased)) AS result
FROM Badges b;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/409604/how-many-tag-badges-have-been-awarded)**</kbd>

---

And one more way. I am not sure why I've written it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 RANK() OVER(ORDER BY TagBased DESC) - 1
FROM Badges b
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo3`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/409626/how-many-tag-badges-have-been-awarded)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways using bit operators.

```
select sum(TagBased&1) from Badges
```

Generally, you can store several bit values in one integer. For example I've 5 types of bages. You can put values like :

- 1 - Code
- 2 - bit
- 4 - byte
- 8 - programing

if you need to set `Code` and `byte` at the same time. It will be `1 + 4 = 5`

Now how to count `Code` bages count

```
select sum(TagBased & 1) from Badges
```

Now how to count `Byte` bages count

```
select sum(TagBased & 4)/4 from Badges
```

Now at the same time, `Code` and `Byte` bages count at all

```
select count(TagBased & 5) from Badges where TagBased & 5 > 0
```